# What does compound let/const assignment mean?

Tags: javascript, bluebird, compound-assignment

There is an article [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) in wiki of Bluebird library. In this article there is a phrase:

> Currently not optimizable: 
>   ...
>   Functions that contain a compound let assignment 
>   Functions that contain a compound const assignment

What does compound let assignment and compound const assignment mean?
In ECMAScript 5.1 there was notion of [compound assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2) but in ECMAScript 2015, it seems there is no notion of any compound assignment there is only regular assignments.

I suspect that compound let and const assignment, it is just compound assignment after declaration. For example:

```
let n = 1;
n += 4;
```

Am I right?

Comment: From the definition of compound: "a thing that is composed of two or more separate elements; a mixture." From that, I would think that `let n = 1 + someval` is a compound assignment and `let n = 1` is not? Couldn't say with absolute confidence though...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be exactly what it means. I had the following code (irrelevant additional lines removed):

```
function updatePlayer(player) {
    let direction = player.getDirection();
    if (player.isPressingLeft()) {
        direction += angleChange;
    }
    if (player.isPressingRight()) {
        direction -= angleChange;
    }
    player.setDirection(direction);
}
```

`updatePlayer` generated a warning, *Not optimized: Unsupported let compound assignment*, in Chrome's *Profiles* tab, so instead of `l += r` I tried `l = l + r` and got a significant, consistent performance improvement.

[jsPerf shows that `let` compound assignments are indeed extremely slow in **Chrome 49.0.2623**](http://jsperf.com/let-compound-assignment), compared to `l = l + r` or `var`! I guess this will be fixed in a future version, since neither Firefox nor IE11 nor Edge is affected, and since Google apparently know about the issue.

Comment: This seems right, but then what is a "compound `const` assignment", since `const` declarations cannot be re-assigned?

Comment: Late to the party, but might also mean `let x = 1, y = x;` instead of `let x = 1; let y = x;`. Just a guess.

Comment: Why the heck does this *still* kill optimization? I see this in `--trace_opt --trace_deopt` all the time. Compound assignment statements like "+=" are way too simple and way too convenient.