# Does "undefined" occupy memory in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

In this situation `var foo;`

Will "foo" point to somewhere in the memory that contains the value `undefined`?

Does `undefined` occupy memory in javascript?
Does `undefined` mean that there is no memory address assigned to a specific label?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Will "foo" point to somewhere in the memory*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two parts to your question. The variable itself and multiple copies of `undefined` value.

First, variables **can** take space in memory. It's not always known if they do take space since compilers can optimize your code in a way that they might not do so (or even straight up removed).

As of the other part of your question. Per the specification there's only one `undefined` value but the specification does not require the implementation to hold a unique representation of `undefined` in memory. So any implementation can hold multiple copies of the value so long as the language semantics can be guaranteed.

Edit: Also, the specification does not specify its value representation in memory, so that's also an implementation detail.

Comment: When JS is defining the scopes (parsing), it will search for declarations, right? for example ` var foo = 2; ` it will see it as two parts the first part `var foo; `, and then later at the execution time, JS Engine will set the value to it, like this `foo = 2; `.
 
So now,  the variable has been set twice, the first time to "undefined", and then to the number 2.
 
What if we used `const` instead. const can't point to a new place in the memory. so, we can't set it twice?
 
What am I missing here?

Comment: @Haitham6373 You seem to refer to [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475965/1048572), and no, that's not really [how it works for `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572).

Comment: `const` is never initialized to `undefined` unless you explicitly do so. `let` and `const` are not initialized until they reach their respective declarations and `const` always require an initializer. `const foo;` is an error.

Answer (score 3):

Any kind of variable you create will occupy memory space, regardless if it was created with `let`, `const` or `var`. When you do it, you're literally telling JS to reserve memory space because you will store values in that variable. `undefined` is a value in JavaScript, therefore, yes, it does consume memory.

There are tests regarding performances between `let` and `var` that leads to some discussion about which is faster ([see this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070631/v8-javascript-performance-implications-of-const-let-and-var)), and `const` is recommended for values you have that won't change.

Comment: "*tests that prove that `let` is faster than `var`*" - I don't see any claims of that in the thread you linked. And a single benchmark doesn't "prove" anything. If you'd just remove that sentence from your post, it would be the perfect answer.

Comment: You're correct, my mistake. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any variable you declare in javascript will be assigned to a memory location. if you don't initialize the variable while declaring, then it will be assigned to `undefined` by `Javascript`. which means you declared a variable and it's not been assigned yet.

`undefined` is a value in javascript.
You can read [here](https://medium.com/@stephenthecurt/a-brief-history-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript-c283caab662e)

Comment: When JS is defining the scopes (parsing), it will search for declarations, right? for example ` var foo = 2; ` it will see it as two parts the first part `var foo; `, and then later at the execution time, JS Engine will set the value to it, like this `foo = 2; `.
 
So now,  the variable has been set twice, the first time to "undefined", and then to the number 2.
 
What if we used `const` instead. const can't point to a new place in the memory. so, we can't set it twice?
 
What am I missing here?

Comment: there is a concept called hoisting in javascript, in this concept the `variable declarations` will be moved to the top before `execution`. so, this is the same for all types of variables regardless of whether it is `var`, `let`, and `const`.  
But while using `const` you can't skip assigning value to it. that's why you don't experience hoisting.
You can read more about hoisting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting